# Linear Programming on a round convex object

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization

So my knowledge in linear programming is quite limited. But I do have an intuition why the simplex method (which in my mind is a greedy GD method) would fail for large number of extreme points.

I am facing a linear optimization problem in which the convex set of possible solutions is not a polytope but rather a round object. My first attempt was to approximate this by a polytope with a large number of extreme points and then run the simplex method. However this takes $long$ for $good$ approximations.

Does anyone know a better method to solve the problem? I would also appreciate a good, thorough source be it a textbook, paper, lecture note, video lecture, etc.

Comment: the simplex method is not greedy, it does not fail and is an exact method. I think you need a more precise mathematical description of your problem.

Comment: You should write more detail about your round convex set. It may fall into some known more specific class of non-linearly constrained optimization problems. And even in the polytope case simplex is not the only algorithm.

Comment: Can you share an explicit example of your problem? As such it is unclear what you are asking.